# Finding a topology for a vector space $X$, such that $X$ is a topologic vector space and the topologic and algebraic dual spaces are the same

Tags: topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Given is a vector space $X \neq \{0\}$. I should find a topology such that $X$ is a topologic vector space and the topologic $X'$ and algebraic $X^*$ dual spaces are the same.

My idea is to use the inital topology on $X$ with respect to $X^*$. Can I now say, that all linear functions are continous as well and therefore $X^* = X'$?

If my idea is not correct, can someone give me idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your idea looks fine. The topological dual of the initial topology coincides with $X^{*}$.

Comment: Thanks, I did prove that $X$ is continous with scalar multiplication and addition. But I don't know how to prove Hausdorff (T2). Can you help me with that?

Comment: Are you familiiar with the topology generated by a family of semi-norms? The topology here is generated by the semi-norms $p_f(x)=|f(x)|$ where $f$ ranges over $X^{*}$. You can refer to Rudin's book for the fact that a separating family of seminorms generates a Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space.

Comment: No, I'm not familiar with the topology created by a family of semi-norms. Our idea was that we choose a $x \neq y$ and that we could find a $f \in X^*$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$. By choosing small disjoint neighbourhoods their inverse image is disjoint as well, because of the continuity. But we don't know if we can find such an $f$ for sure

Comment: Using the existence of Hamel basis you can prove that such an $f$ exists. If $x$ and $y$ are independent extend $\{x,y\}$ to a basis and define $f(x)=0,f(y)=1$ and $f(z)=0$ for all other basis elements.  This $f$ extends to a linear map on the whole space. Can you handle the case when $x$ and $y$ are dependent?

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved it now